# Angularjs - Number Filter Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently learning angularjs and it is pretty cool. Can't wait to check the other frameworks. I have been trying to create a simple web app, but have encountered a problem when retrieving a value from a scope and using a Number Filter

Basically I have 3 inputs: `total, down(down payment), balance`

When I enter an amount in the total input, automatically it would show the current down payment and the remaining balance.

This is the code without the Number Filter (WORKING)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, numberFilter) {    

$scope.getAmount = function() {
    var total = Number($scope.total || 0);
    $scope.down = total*.2;
    $scope.balance = total-$scope.down;
}
});
```

This is the code with the Number Filter (Not working Properly)

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, numberFilter) {    

$scope.getAmount = function() {
    var total = Number($scope.total || 00);
    $scope.down = numberFilter(total*.2);
    $scope.balance = numberFilter(total-$scope.down);
}
});
```

It displays the down payment value properly but for the balance it's value just disappears when it reaches a higher value.

this is my html

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<label>TOTAL AMOUNT</label> 
<input type="number" ng-model="total" ng-keyup="getAmount()">

<br><br>

<label>DOWNPAYMENT</label>  
<input type="text" ng-model="down">

<br><br>

<label>BALANCE</label>  
<input type="text" ng-model="balance">
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help! :D

Comment: why are u using document ready function

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I was using jquery also for my project so I just created a new project to isolate and figure out the problem that''s why it's there haha sorry about that.